# Initializing dateTimePicker to today's date but date not showing in text portion of control

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I am setting DateTimePicker value to today's date.

```
dtDate.Checked = true;
dtDate.Value = System.DateTime.Today;
if (dtDate.Handle == null)
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0);
dtDate.Checked = false;
```

Calendar date gets set which is confirmed by accessing the calendar.
However the text is blank.
How do I get it to show the date in the text portion of the control?

Comment: This works for me. What else is the rest of your code doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this way. It works fine for me.

```
dtDate.Text = dtDate.Value.ToString();
```

The text that will be shown will depend on the mask you are using on `dtDate`